# Java txt parser new line issue

Tags: java, parsing

Good Morning. Having trouble with a parser using split method. Goal is to read in txt file, extract should statements, then write a new txt file with those should statements. I have it working when the text is on one continuous line. If I have a new line in the txt file, rewrites the file with just the last line. Possibly the structure of my loops? Also any suggestions for saving new file from the directory in which it was opened? Thank you

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/*This Program Will launch a File Explorer.
User will then chose a .txt file to be parsed.
A new file will be created labeled "Parsed_(Document Name)".*/

public class Parser {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        Scanner userFile = new Scanner(System.in);

        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            try {
                System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName() + "\n");

                File file = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
                String newFile = ("Parsed_" + file);

                userFile = new Scanner(file);

                while (userFile.hasNextLine()) {

                    String document = userFile.nextLine();
                    // Line breaks used by Parser
                    String[] sentences = document.split("\\.|\\?|\\!|\\r");

                    List<String> ShouldArray = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (String shouldStatements : sentences) {

                        if (shouldStatements.contains("Should") || shouldStatements.contains("should"))
                            ShouldArray.add(shouldStatements);

                    }

                    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(newFile);
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);

                    for (String shallStatements : ShouldArray) {

                        System.out.println(shallStatements);

                        bw.append(shallStatements);
                        bw.newLine();

                    }

                    System.out.println("\nParsed Document Created: " + newFile);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Parsed Document Created: " + newFile);
                    bw.close();

                    writer.close();

                }

                userFile.close();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test file 1 (works!)

Hello all. Here is a a packing list. You Should have a toothbrush. You should have a Phone charger. And you definitely should have your wallet!

Test file 1 output:

You Should have a toothbrush
 You Should have a Phone charger
 And you definitely should have your wallet

Test file 2 (Only printing last line)

Hello all. Here is a a packing list. You Should have a toothbrush. You Should have a Phone charger. 
Here is some random text to show the parser will not include this.
You definitely should have your wallet!

test file 2 output:

You definitely should have your wallet

Comment: Looks like you are looping the while loop for each new line. Then you create a new file each loop and print a line. So after 1 line, you overwrite the previous statement.

Comment: How about you set the scanner delimiter to be punctuation and newlines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding your Arraylist within the  loop, however you don't actually need it

```
File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " + file.getName() + "\n");

String newFile = "Parsed_" + file.getName();

// open all closable objects using try-with-resources 
try (Scanner userFile = new Scanner(file); 
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile))) {

   while (userFile.hasNextLine()) {
      String document = userFile.nextLine();
     // Line breaks used by Parser
     String[] sentences = document.split("\\.|\\?|\\!|\\r");

    for (String s : sentences) {
        if (s.contains("Should") || s.contains("should")) {
            System.out.println(s);
            bw.append(s);
            bw.newLine();
      }
   } 

   System.out.println("\nParsed Document Created: " + newFile);

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Parsed Document Created: " + newFile);
   // bw.close(); // not needed anymore
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your result array outside of the loop

```
 /** Placed here**/
 List<String> ShouldArray = new ArrayList<String>();
 while (userFile.hasNextLine()) {

                String document = userFile.nextLine();
                // Line breaks used by Parser
                String[] sentences = document.split("\\.|\\?|\\!|\\r");

                /** REMOVED HERE **/

                for (String shouldStatements : sentences) {

                    if (shouldStatements.contains("Should") || shouldStatements.contains("should"))
                        ShouldArray.add(shouldStatements);

                }
               ......
```

otherwise you will only gather the results of your last loop.

Basically what your code was doing:

```
cut up file in lines
take each line
    take next line
     make a result board.
     write results on board
    take next line
     erase board
     write results on board
    take next line
     erase board
     write results on board
```

and then at the end there is only a limited resultset on your board

Answer (score 1):

I've refactored the code, removing the "ShouldArray", which is not needed.

Pseudocode

```
While there are lines to read in the In file
    Read each line
    Split each line into Array of sentences

    Loop through each sentence
        If each sentence contains Should or should Then
          Write sentence to Out file
        End If
    End Loop
End While

Close Out file
Close In file
```

The code below works with:

Multi line:

```
Hello all. Here is a a packing list.
You Should have a toothbrush. You Should have a Phone charger.
Here is some random text to show the parser will not include this.
You definitely should have your wallet!
```

Single line:

```
Hello all. Here is a a packing list. You Should have a toothbrush. You should have a Phone charger. And you definitely should have your wallet!
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;

public class ShouldStringsParser {

    public ShouldStringsParser(String inFile, String outFile) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(inFile);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outFile);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        Scanner userFile;
        userFile = new Scanner(file);
        String[] sentences;

        while (userFile.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = userFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);

            sentences = line.split("\\.|\\?|\\!|\\r");

            for (String shouldStatements : sentences) {
                if (shouldStatements.contains("Should") || shouldStatements.contains("should")) {
                    System.out.println(">>>" + shouldStatements);
                    bw.append(shouldStatements);
                    bw.newLine();
                }
            }
        }

        bw.close();
        writer.close();
        userFile.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new ShouldStringsParser("inDataMultiLine.txt", "outDataMultiLine.txt");

            new ShouldStringsParser("inDataSingleLine.txt", "outDataSingleLine.txt");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```